# How to Permit multiple parameters to rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yULNPCbrSyV/AeJqx9Phvg4yk7pWMjJ5BYpm4JVLr0SZ3zZdvEmvSUjKGqgH9XOwFEoS07wG5d9vrilsyntpCA==", "task"=>{"title"=>"smtp", "complexity"=>"high", "best_case_estimation"=>"333", "worst_case_estimation"=>"33"}, "button"=>"", "project_lead_id"=>"94", "task_module_id"=>"11"}
```

Comment: please add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "strong parameters" and is implemented by Rails to help ensure certain parameters aren't touched unless they're supposed to be.  Looking at your parameters you have a task object (so a task form) being submitted so you'll have to whitelist those parameters if you're looking to update an object via "mass assignment".  There is a ton of documentation on the subject and I highly recommend getting familiar with this concept since it's used very heavily.  What you'll want to do is the following in your controller:

```
private

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:complexity, :title, :best_case_estimation)
end
```

Make sure to add this at the bottom since it's stating that all methods below the private line will be in fact considered "private" methods. Now you can add something like this in the 'create' action of that controller:

```
   def create
      @task = Task.new(task_params)
      if @task.save
        #stuff here
      else

      end
    end
```